# Have to call angular service twice in order for it to call my api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I've started writing code in angular and seem to have gotten stuck. I have created a simple service that will call my API to delete an item in a database. I am calling my service that I created the following way:

```
studentService.del(
  { token: localStorage.getItem('token'), studentId: studentInfo.studentId },
  function (result) {
    console.log('im in delete FE callback');
    if (result[0].studentDeleted) {
        $scope.showSimpleToast('Deleted');
    }
  }
)
```

The weird thing that occurs with this is that both my service and the call to the service works. If i hit the delete button to remove a student the request will be made, but will not call the api for ~15 seconds, I'll get a status of pending in my chrome console. however, if i click the delete button twice it will delete the student instantly (no pending period). Does anyone have an idea as to why this could be occurring so i could investigate into it?

Important things to note:

1. Angular version - 1.5.8
2. using $resource for my restful API call
3. i have console logs in my function that calls studentService.del, i see that I'm entering the function when i click delete, but i do not see the log statement for the API or front end within the callback of the function the console log that I am not seeing is labeled as "I'm in delete FE callback". I will eventually see this and the API log statement if i wait ~15 seconds, or call the function twice.

I use an ng-repeat to populate a list of students and read that perhaps its taking so long to execute because it is not executing until the next $digest cycle, I'm not sure if this is happening or not, but is this a possibility? if so how would i go about fixing this?

Comment: Please also post the code the service where you're making api calls. There is no use in posting code that is already working correctly.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).